# Measure vertical distance travelled

Tags: sensor, msp430, accelerometer

I wonder if it's usually practical to use an accelerometer to measure the height of a ball tossed in the air. That is, would it be accurate to integrate the acceleration measured over time twice? An accelerometer like the [MPU6050](https://www.invensense.com/products/motion-tracking/6-axis/mpu-6050/) has DMP for calculating pitch, roll, and yaw but nothing for height. Would it be too slow to integrate `ay` twice on a low-end MCU like the MSP430?

Edit: The height of travel will be less than 10cm.

Comment: No. It is not very practical. Use a barometer instead.

Comment: @mkeith I'm actually expecting a height of less than 100mm, so I don't think there'll be any significant change in pressure.

Comment: A lot of the MEMS barometers I've seen can discern a cm or so of altitude change. Not what I'd call 'stellar performance' for your application, but then, I don't know what precision you need.

Answer (score 1):

All an accelerometer will give you is time of flight.

while the ball is in the air it's in free-fall and the accelerometer will read zero.

if you can assume a level playing field you can calculate maximum height from time of flight.

for 10cm height time of flight will be about 200ms

throw in a 3 axis gyro, and you can estimate how hard it was thrown
and and how much of that throw was vertical, but time of flight is probably still your best bet.

Comment: Right. But why a gyro and not an accelerometer? Wouldn't I want to measure the linear acceleration instead?

Comment: @JohnMunroe - Unless you can guarantee that the ball is thrown along the sensitive axis of the accelerometer, you'll need a 3-axis accelerometer, along with some software to combine the 3 axes worth of data to synthesize the actual acceleration, and even then you won't know if the throw was vertical - that's what you need the gyros for. You'd need to determine the local g vector (most easily done at rest, but not necessarily), then keep track of rotations to determine the vertical component of your launch acceleration. And gyro drift will be the biggest source of error.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast If I'm only interested in the vertical displacement, wouldn't only the vertical linear acceleration be relevant? That is, there'd be no need to keep track of rotations - am I right?

Comment: @JohnMunroe - Only if "you can guarantee that the ball is thrown along the sensitive axis of the accelerometer". Can you make that guarantee? If so, you only need one.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast But if the ball wasn't thrown along the sensitive axis, wouldn't the height still be picked up by the accelerometer? For instance, if the ball was spinning and thrown as a projectile, wouldn't `acc_y` still represent the vertical linear acceleration? Thus, even with the spin (rotation) and travel along other axes (projectile), wouldn't integrating `acc_y` twice still give the vertical displacement?

Comment: @JohnMunroe - Sorry, no. An accelerometer only measures acceleration along a single axis. It is up to you to guarantee that that axis corresponds to the acceleration force. As an analogy, consider a bathroom scale. This is force sensitive (rather than acceleration) along an axis which is nominally vertical. Putting sideways force on the scale will give no reading. Same idea for accelrometer. It is perfectly possible to make a system such as you envision which will not respoind at all to vertical acceleration.

Comment: @JohnMunroe  while the ball is in flight (ignoring drag) it is not accelerating, (see  "General relativity") while the ball is "as rest" the accelerometer sees ground pushing against it as an acceleration.

Comment: from a frame of reference of an observer standing on the ground, timing the flight is equivalent to integrating the gravitational acceleration,  it won't tell you current height, but when it lands  (about 100ms late) you'll know how high it went. (assuming no aerodynamic effects)